# Which are the exact requirements for the "Destroyer of Worlds" achievement?

Tags: achievements, starbound

The steam description for the achievement is "Move a planet's worth of blocks", which seems fairly vague. Before I start grinding blocks to try to get it, I was wondering if anyone has a more specific description, potential covering:

1. Whether "moving" only means breaking the blocks, or also placing them back down elsewhere
2. Whether you have to fully destroy a single planet, or if it's a cumulative count of blocks broken overall that needs to reach a certain number (if so, how many blocks need to be mined)
3. Whether liquids and background tiles count
4. Whether bombs/explosives count, or just mining with pickaxes/the matter manipulator.
5. Whether blocks can be player-placed, or if they have to be naturally generated

My best guess so far is that it's a cumulative count, and only involves breaking the blocks. I have no idea for the last 3 details, though, and I'd like some kind of source such as game code or experiments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be picking up blocks what counts, so picking up 10 000 000 of them from the ground is all that is needed.

The magic number can be found in the `achievements\achievements\itemsplanetblocks.achievement` file (extracted from `Starbound\assets\packed.pak`)

```
{
  "name" : "planetblocks",

  "triggers" : [
    "item.category.block"
  ],
  "scripts" : [ "/achievements/achievement.lua" ],

  "stats" : [
    {
      "name" : "item.category.block",
      "op" : "atLeast",
      "value" : 10000000
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking in the `Starbound\storage\player\statistics` file there seems to be a counter for `item.category.block`.

Leveraging [py-starbound](https://github.com/blixt/py-starbound) by renaming the statistics file to `statistics.player` and running `cli.py -g stats statistics.player` to dump the file in a readable format and comparing the number before and after picking up some blocks from the ground in game it seems `item.category.block` counts any blocks picked up.

To verify I created a new character and loaded his blocks inventory up with 40k blocks:
[image: New character with 40k blocks in inventory]

And constructed a suicide pit at the beam down spot:
[image: Suicide pit at planet spawn]

After 227 suicides and re-spawns I got the achievement. Since you pick up the 40k blocks you drop on death each time you jump in the lava pit, 250 suicides will get you 10 000 000 blocks picked up if you haven't played at all.

Answer (score 2):

I found my way to do it is to block yourself in the teleporter spot of your ship (where you respawn) and type /suicide over and over with your inventory filled with blocks. It took me about 9 minutes to get 5 million blocks so I belive this to be the fastest way to get it.

Answer (score -1):

To figure out how far you've come, run a script like the below.

I've copied my 'statistics' file to the current directory as 'stats.player' so I'm not at risk of modifying the actual game files.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import starbound
fh=open("stats.player", 'rb')
player=starbound.read_sbvj01(fh)
count=player.data['stats']['item.category.block']['value']
total=10000000
print("User collected %s blocks, thus %d%% the way to 'Destroyer of Worlds'" %
   (f'{count:,}', 100 * float(count)/ float(total)))
```

The output for me:

> $ ./print-stats.py
> User collected 2,147,771 blocks, thus 21% the way to 'Destroyer of Worlds'

I have to swim in lava a little longer...

Comment: While helpful, this does not actually answer the question on its own.

Answer (score -4):

I believe people are say that its destroy at least 10000000 blocks and pick them up.

Comment: Got a source for that?

Comment: this is ... so much better than any of the solutions i came up with